# For loop not outputting properly when using arrays

Tags: vb.net

I would expect this code when run to output the first line of the array, pause, then output the second line in the array, each line being output with a delay between each character but for some reason it isn't working for me.

```
        Dim IntroText(4) As String
    IntroText(0) = "Konrad Czajkowski..."
    IntroText(1) = "...Presents"
    IntroText(2) = "...A text based game..."
    IntroText(3) = "...The Legend of Konrad and The Quest for Skairum"

    Dim IntroTextLength As Integer = Nothing
    IntroTextLength = IntroText(IntroText.Length - 1)

    For IntroCounter1 = 0 To IntroTextLength
        For IntroCounter2 = 0 To IntroText(IntroCounter1).Length - 1
            Console.Write(IntroText(IntroTextLength)(IntroCounter2))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Next
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Console.Clear()
    Next
    Console.Clear()
```

P.s I'm using a console application in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim IntroText(4) As String
IntroText(0) = "Konrad Czajkowski..."
IntroText(1) = "...Presents"
IntroText(2) = "...A text based game..."
IntroText(3) = "...The Legend of Konrad and The Quest for Skairum"

Dim IntroTextLength As Integer = Nothing
IntroTextLength = IntroText.Length - 1

For IntroCounter1 = 0 To IntroTextLength - 1
    For IntroCounter2 = 0 To IntroText(IntroCounter1).Length - 1
        Console.Write(IntroText(IntroCounter1)(IntroCounter2))
        'Console.Write(IntroTextLength)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Next
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Console.Clear()
Next
Console.Clear()
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you, couldn't fix it myself, practicing vb for later in life, I'm in college and this is very valuable feedback. Thanks!

Comment: It's good that this fixed the OPs problem but it would be worth explaining why.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  You should at least try to explain why the OP code was incorrect and what your code does to fix the problem.